# Determining symbol addresses using binutils/readelf

Tags: elf, debug-symbols, dwarf, readelf

I am working on a project where our verification test scripts need to locate symbol addresses within the build of software being tested.  This might be used for setting breakpoints or reading static data from memory.  What I am after is to create a map file containing symbol names, base address in memory, and size.  Our build outputs an ELF file which has the information I want.  I've been trying to use the *readelf, nm, and objdump* tools to try and to gain the symbol addresses I need.

I originally tried `readelf -s file.elf` and that seemed to access some symbols, particularly those which were written in assembler.  However, many of the symbols that I wanted were not in there - specifically those that originated within our Ada code.

I used `readelf --debug-dump file.elf` to dump all debug information.  From that I do see all symbols, including those that were in the Ada code.  However, the format seems to be in the DWARF format.  Does anyone know why these symbols would not be output by readelf when I ask it to list the symbolic information?  Perhaps there is simply an option I am missing.

Now I could go to the trouble of writing a custom DWARF parser to get the information but if I can get it using one of the Binutils (nm, readelf, objdump) then I'd really like prefer a standard solution.

Answer (score 6):

DWARF is the debug information and tries to reflect the relation of the original source code. Taking following code as an example

```
static int one() {
  // something
  return 1;
}
int main(int ac, char **av) {
  return one();
}
```

After you compile it using `gcc -O3 -g`, the static function `one` will be inlined into `main`. So when you use `readelf -s`, you will never see the symbol `one`. However, when you use `readelf --debug-dump`, you can see `one` is a function which is inlined.

So, in this example, compiler does not prohibit you use optimization with `-g`, so you can still debug the executable. In that example, even the function is optimized and inlined, gdb still can use DWARF information to know the function and source/line from current code block inside inlined function.

Above is just a case of compiler optimization. There might be plenty of reasons that could lead to mismatch symbols address between `readelf -s` and DWARF.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful response.  It seems that I will need to look at the DWARF information to decipher the symbolic information that I am after.  Does anyone have experience with an existing tool to do this?  I'm looking for basic functionality to just determine address and size information given a symbol, or better yet expression.  I have been looking at the **libdwarf** project.  Has anyone used this with success?  If anyone knows of other tools then I would be glad to know of it.  Thanks.